# PrimeNG Angular2 css dialog box

Tags: angular, primeng

Hello I've been working with angular2 and PrimeNG
I have the following problem: I have a dialog box I can't resize vertically dynamically.

```
<div ng-reflect-raw-class="[object Object]" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-dialog-draggable" style="display: block; visibility: visible; left: 250px; top: 67px; z-index: 1040; opacity: 1.056; width: 563px; ">
            <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-top">


<p-dialog header="User details" [(visible)]="displayDialog" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true">
```

If I add a height="500" or something else the height of the dialog box will change but will look like this:

[image]

I would like to have the save button at the bottom and be able to see everything. when room is available.

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .ui-dropdown-item span{
    font-size: 12px;
}

.ui-dropdown-items-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #b4b1b0;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

The right way is to change in style.css 
it  resolved my problem .

Answer (score -1):

The easy way is to add a few `<br>` or a fixed height div after the combo

PS: I have notice that you have been trying to add a class to the dialog using styleClass, do not add brackets.

Example:

`<p-dialog header="User details" [(visible)]="displayDialog" [responsive]="true" showEffect="fade" [modal]="true" styleClass="userdialog">`

Answer (score -1):

The right way is to change in style.css

```
.ui-dropdown-panel {
    position: inherit !important;   
    top:0px !important;  
}
```

[image: before open]
[image: after open]